# AngularJS : Chrome hidden fields value don't update after page return

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is managed with AngularJS.
I use on ng-repeat dropdonw list to update a hidden field value.
Everything works fine until I use chrome and submit the code and then do a

> "page return/Go back one page"

If i try to use the dropdonw list again it only updates the modal value in a print statement not the value of the hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="postageId" value="{{intPostageId}}" ng-model="intPostageId" />{{intPostageId}}
```

{{intPostageId}} outside the input works, but the one inside doesn't update

Much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason angular doesn't update hidden input values with ng-model.  You will have to do a quite directive to get this to work.

You don't need the value binding you have ng-model will be enough.

```
module.directive('updateHidden', function () {
    return function (scope, el, attr) {
        var model = attr.ngModel;
        scope.$watch(model, function (val) {
            el.val(val);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I will try this. thanks. Only chrome seems to have the problem and that is when I do a return with go back.Cheers

Comment: @super_ton you don't need the value binding - ng-model will be enough

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="postageId" ng-model="intPostageId" update-hidden /> something like this seems to work using your code. I'm soo new at this....

Comment: Glad it worked.  Keep going you will get it Angular is such a good framework it is worth the initial learning curve :-)

Comment: seems to fix my small problem with chrome too!! amazing !! sorry I can't give +1 - not enough reputation!! I would never figure that out !!!

Comment: I should have read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem myself. No idea why this happens but and an easy workaround I found for this is to just swap the hidden field for a text field with display:none

```
<input type="text" name="postageId" value="{{intPostageId}}" style="display:none">
```